# Angular spiderweb chart properties gridLineInterpolation give error "does not exist in type 'AxisOptions | AxisOptions[]'"

Tags: angular, highcharts

The following code block works fine with all the properties in fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pgc2ovdj/6/

but when i use the same properties in my angular project using typescript it does not recognize the following properties
 **yAxis.gridLineInterpolation** and **plotOptions.series.grouping**

I am using the following dependencies:

```
"angular-highcharts": "^6.2.6",
"highcharts": "^6.2.0",

"@types/highcharts": "^5.0.31",
```

*TypeScript Version: 2.3*

```
import { Highcharts,Chart } from 'angular-highcharts';



Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    polar: true,
},
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Sales', 'Marketing', 'Development', 'Customer Support',
        'Information Technology', 'Administration'],
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
    lineWidth: 0
},

yAxis: {
    gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
    lineWidth: 0,
    min: 0
},
plotOptions: {
   series:{
        grouping: true,
        stacking:'column',
   }
},
tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>${point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>'
},

series: [{
    name: 'Allocated Budget',
    data: [43000, 19000, 60000, 35000, 17000, 10000],
    pointPlacement: 'on'
}, {
    name: 'Actual Spending',
    data: [50000, 39000, 42000, 31000, 26000, 14000],
    pointPlacement: 'on'
}]
```

});

Comment: Simple type error. Try with `Highcharts.chart('container', <any>{ ... })`

Comment: @trichetriche if we user it with " new Chart({" then what's the solution ?

Comment: Well apparently you don't. And if you did, I don't know. I don't know the library, but I know the error. This is an issue with the typings, that don't recognize the property. You can try to rewrite your own definition file, or use an `any` typing.

Comment: thanks , the issue is resolved